# How to force Mac to into dirty shutdown state on every power off?

Tags: macos, hardware, kernel

As Far as I can tell no one has actually solved this debacle.
How do you get a mac mini to power on every time the UPS it is connected to restores power?
It is easy enough to have the UPS communicate that power is about to turn off so have the mac run the command halt -u, or shutdown -h -u, etc, and many solutions such as powerchute from APC guarantee that it will shutdown etc. But it is not guaranteed that the mac will turn back on. If this bit/ file was permanently set so mac the mac believed that it dirty shutdown every time, whatever hardware is responsible for the power sensing of the power restored would always boot the mac when power is restored, even if the mini was powered off during while it booted. Currently if your mini powers off without dirty shutdown being set you are boned, and you must physically press the power button on the back for it to restart, which is unacceptable if the mini is says 5000 miles away or at the bottom of the ocean. You should be able to get this functionality even if no UPS is involved just by having the mac always try to reboot when power is restored. Has anyone ever figured this out?

Comment: Should this be on superuser.com?

Comment: Check EFI settings. It could be there. Such options are in BIOS on IBM compatible PCs. Also, from question format, superuser seems like the site for it. If you need access EFI using a program, please edit the question to show that.

Comment: thank you I posted this on superuser.com. I was hoping that this may be able to be done through some low level programming interface, maybe something in I/O Kit power management which I'm not terrible familiar with

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this (10.12 sierra).  How did you solve it years ago?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the setting in the Energy Saver preference panel?

```
System Preferences
  -> Energy Saver
     -> Options
        -> Restart automatically after a power failure
```

Or see `man pmset`:

```
$ pmset -a autorestart 1
```

Comment: This answer is not correct this only works if the mac has the power cut, not in the case of a proper shut down which would require shutdown -h u to restore power from a g3 power state. more here http://superuser.com/questions/158654/how-to-force-mac-to-into-dirty-shutdown-state-on-every-power-off. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: Oh, I see.  Back in the old days, Macs with ADBs had power buttons on the keyboard and so there were small third-party boxes that could be plugged into an ADB port and signal a hardware power on - something lost in the move to industry-standard USB keyboards.

Answer (score 2):

Ned almost had the answer - it's on [the man page][1][(Apple copy, currently broken)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) he mentioned.

```
pmset schedule [cancel] type date+time [owner]
  -g sched displays scheduled startup/wake and shutdown/sleep events.
```

Have a shutdown script run pmset to schedule the system to wake up half an hour or so (let the power stabilize and the UPS time to recharge) from now.

Oh, and BTW: looking through the output of `pmset -g everything`, I see:

```
INVOKE: pmset -g ups
UPS settings:
  haltlevel off 0
  haltafter off 0
  haltremain    off 0
```

[1]: Oddly, Apple has taken down its web-formatted man pages; best I can find: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pmset/

Comment: I can't see his man page link! Do you think you could include it in your answer?